# Flip the orientation of all keyframed bones in an animation

Tags: animation, armature, bones, transforms

[image]
i have skeleton **A**, which i made animations for to use in a game engine.

now, i'm trying to import the same character that i made with the same skeleton to another game engine

the other game engine expects the skeleton to be flipped, which i have done as skeleton **B** (same hierarchy, same bones names, etc)

i want to re-use all the animations i made for skeleton **A** on skeleton **B**, but if i try to play an animation on skeleton **B**, this happens:
[image]

all the bones orientations are flipped

and my question is, how can i edit the animations to "flip" the bone orientations so they are properly aligned with skeleton **B**?

i tried to do that using the Graph Editor by manually adjusting the orientation for each bone, but i'm wondering if there is an easier/faster way to achieve this goal